# Is it normal to have so much netstat output?

Tags: linux, connection

I came across this problem where I saw a lot of connections in my machine and I don't know if this is normal. I even have a ssh agent when I don't have sshd even installed. I just want to know if this is normal and if it is not, how can I close them.

Here is the output of `netstat -a`:

```
Conexiones activas de Internet (servidores y establecidos)
Proto  Recib Enviad Dirección local         Dirección remota       Estado      
tcp        0      0 localhost:ipp           0.0.0.0:*               ESCUCHAR   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:hostmon         0.0.0.0:*               ESCUCHAR   
tcp        0      0 MAKINA:51738            mad01s26-in-f174.:https ESTABLECIDO
tcp        0      0 MAKINA:49462            mad01s25-in-f202.:https ESTABLECIDO
tcp        0      0 MAKINA:51750            mad01s26-in-f174.:https ESTABLECIDO
tcp        1      0 MAKINA:51358            annarchy.freedesk:https CLOSE_WAIT 
tcp        0      0 MAKINA:37020            mad06s25-in-f132.:https ESTABLECIDO
tcp        0      0 MAKINA:51486            mad01s26-in-f3.1e:https ESTABLECIDO
tcp      413      0 MAKINA:51754            mad01s26-in-f174.:https ESTABLECIDO
tcp      375      0 MAKINA:51502            mad01s26-in-f3.1e:https ESTABLECIDO
tcp        0      0 MAKINA:41950            mad01s26-in-f10.1:https ESTABLECIDO
tcp        1      0 MAKINA:45584            mad06s25-in-f3.1e:https CLOSE_WAIT 
tcp        0      0 MAKINA:45582            mad06s25-in-f3.1e:https ESTABLECIDO
tcp        1      0 MAKINA:51356            annarchy.freedesk:https CLOSE_WAIT 
tcp        0      0 MAKINA:51756            mad01s26-in-f174.:https ESTABLECIDO
tcp        0      0 MAKINA:51504            mad01s26-in-f3.1e:https ESTABLECIDO
tcp        0      0 MAKINA:51500            mad01s26-in-f3.1e:https ESTABLECIDO
tcp        0      0 MAKINA:48900            mad01s26-in-f1.1e:https ESTABLECIDO
tcp        0      0 MAKINA:51732            mad01s26-in-f174.:https ESTABLECIDO
tcp6       0      0 ip6-localhost:ipp       [::]:*                  ESCUCHAR   
tcp6       0      0 [::]:hostmon            [::]:*                  ESCUCHAR   
udp        0      0 localhost:domain        0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:bootpc          0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:ipp             0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50980           0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:mdns            0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:mdns            0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:hostmon         0.0.0.0:*                          
udp6       0      0 [::]:48321              [::]:*                             
udp6       0      0 [::]:mdns               [::]:*                             
udp6       0      0 [::]:mdns               [::]:*                             
udp6       0      0 [::]:hostmon            [::]:*                             
raw6       0      0 [::]:ipv6-icmp          [::]:*                  7          
Activar zócalos de dominio UNIX (servidores y establecidos)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   Ruta
unix  2      [ ACC ]     FLUJO      ESCUCHANDO    28442    @/tmp/.ICE-unix/1805
unix  2      [ ACC ]     FLUJO      ESCUCHANDO    43042    /var/run/cups/cups.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     FLUJO      ESCUCHANDO    28699    @/tmp/.X11-unix/X0
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    95785    /run/wpa_supplicant/wlp4s0
unix  2      [ ACC ]     FLUJO      ESCUCHANDO    24878    /var/run/NetworkManager/private-dhcp
unix  2      [ ACC ]     FLUJO      ESCUCHANDO    23491    @/tmp/ibus/dbus-D0rlMWko
unix  2      [ ACC ]     FLUJO      ESCUCHANDO    28136    /tmp/ssh-XyulgdXVUau9/agent.1513
unix  2      [ ACC ]     FLUJO      ESCUCHANDO    28443    /tmp/.ICE-unix/1805
unix  2      [ ACC ]     FLUJO      ESCUCHANDO    54396    @/tmp/dbus-G17q3MF80w
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    95814    /run/wpa_supplicant/p2p-dev-wlp4s0
unix  2      [ ACC ]     FLUJO      ESCUCHANDO    31048    /run/user/1000/pulse/native
unix  3      [ ]         DGRAM                    14666    /run/systemd/notify
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    14668    /run/systemd/cgroups-agent
unix  2      [ ACC ]     FLUJO      ESCUCHANDO    14672    /run/systemd/private
unix  2      [ ACC ]     FLUJO      ESCUCHANDO    14677    /run/systemd/fsck.progress
unix  22     [ ]         DGRAM                    14680    /run/systemd/journal/dev-log
unix  2      [ ACC ]     FLUJO      ESCUCHANDO    14684    /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  8      [ ]         DGRAM                    14686    /run/systemd/journal/socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     SEQPACKET  ESCUCHANDO    14689    /run/udev/control
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    14691    /run/systemd/journal/syslog
unix  2      [ ACC ]     FLUJO      ESCUCHANDO    20330    /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     FLUJO      ESCUCHANDO    20333    /run/acpid.socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     FLUJO      ESCUCHANDO    20335    /run/uuidd/request
unix  2      [ ACC ]     FLUJO      ESCUCHANDO    28700    /tmp/.X11-unix/X0
unix  2      [ ACC ]     FLUJO      ESCUCHANDO    29073    /run/user/1000/keyring/control
unix  2      [ ACC ]     FLUJO      ESCUCHANDO    34207    /tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.YNUbnW/SingletonSocket
unix  3      [ ]         SEQPACKET  CONECTADO     30585    @0001d
unix  2      [ ACC ]     FLUJO      ESCUCHANDO    22197    /run/snapd.socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     FLUJO      ESCUCHANDO    22199    /run/snapd-snap.socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     FLUJO      ESCUCHANDO    22201    /var/run/avahi-daemon/socket
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    28096    /run/user/1000/systemd/notify
unix  2      [ ACC ]     FLUJO      ESCUCHANDO    28100    /run/user/1000/systemd/private
unix  2      [ ACC ]     FLUJO      ESCUCHANDO    28105    /run/user/1000/bus
unix  2      [ ACC ]     FLUJO      ESCUCHANDO    31020    @/tmp/dbus-7fOMHW7yZa
unix  2      [ ACC ]     FLUJO      ESCUCHANDO    25046    /run/user/1000/keyring/pkcs11
unix  2      [ ACC ]     FLUJO      ESCUCHANDO    25049    /run/user/1000/keyring/ssh
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     29593    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     30540    @/tmp/ibus/dbus-D0rlMWko
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     30438    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     30374    /run/user/1000/bus
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     31183    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     22287    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     21363    /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     41398    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     23421    /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     25490    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     32823    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     30416    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     29392    /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     30134    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     22941    /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     48132    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     32883    /run/user/1000/bus
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     31768    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     26549    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     22420    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     28255    /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     25082    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     24980    
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    3975     
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     97018    /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     44088    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     32303    @/tmp/ibus/dbus-D0rlMWko
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    30142    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     21360    /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     40181    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     28181    /run/user/1000/bus
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    22431    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     28544    /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     28367    /run/user/1000/bus
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    26422    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     29270    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     60969    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     37180    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     25538    /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     32080    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     28538    /run/user/1000/bus
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    28811    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     28456    /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    26575    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     28254    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     27401    /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     23465    /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  3      [ ]         DGRAM                    14737    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     96048    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     38068    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     25544    /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     28180    /run/user/1000/bus
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     26550    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     24420    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     25546    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     28319    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     30857    /run/user/1000/bus
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     24983    /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     20391    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     29602    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     34086    @/tmp/.X11-unix/X0
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     31881    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     61228    /run/user/1000/bus
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     16374    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     19162    /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     28537    @/tmp/.X11-unix/X0
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     31800    @/tmp/.X11-unix/X0
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     24487    /run/user/1000/bus
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     28052    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     28604    @/tmp/ibus/dbus-D0rlMWko
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     24975    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     37333    /run/user/1000/bus
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     28542    @/tmp/dbus-7fOMHW7yZa
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     30028    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     22572    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     19172    /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     25449    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     34012    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     29384    /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     23506    
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    25312    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     32198    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     32825    @/tmp/dbus-7fOMHW7yZa
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     31882    /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     28812    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     32824    @/tmp/dbus-7fOMHW7yZa
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     27644    @/tmp/.X11-unix/X0
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     27169    /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  3      [ ]         SEQPACKET  CONECTADO     34589    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     27614    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     25311    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     27810    
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    61151    
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    32199    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     30415    
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    30001    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     32195    /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     22272    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     46725    /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     24419    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     25810    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     23741    /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     32291    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     34192    @/tmp/.X11-unix/X0
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     34085    @/tmp/.X11-unix/X0
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     30024    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     21377    /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     24485    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     35882    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     33813    /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     25178    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     24899    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     3971     
unix  2      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     44093    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     38065    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     37221    
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    30353    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     30889    /run/user/1000/bus
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     22277    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     47640    /run/user/1000/bus
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     42205    /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     31799    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     24402    @/tmp/.X11-unix/X0
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     34594    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     25045    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     27341    /run/user/1000/bus
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     29075    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     27710    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     37984    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     30360    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     30131    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     31147    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     4051     /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     19171    /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     32885    /run/user/1000/bus
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     27643    @/tmp/dbus-7fOMHW7yZa
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     28448    /run/user/1000/bus
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     27452    /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     26887    /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     49921    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     42196    /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     27618    /run/user/1000/bus
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     29258    /run/user/1000/bus
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     3058     
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     19166    /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     25313    @/tmp/.X11-unix/X0
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     28989    /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     55357    @/tmp/dbus-G17q3MF80w
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     25460    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     25215    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     31185    @/tmp/dbus-7fOMHW7yZa
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     28531    @/tmp/.X11-unix/X0
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     30331    
unix  3      [ ]         DGRAM                    14670    
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    34031    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     31850    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     29341    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     28365    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     26391    /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     24981    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     29084    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     26853    /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     33423    @/tmp/.X11-unix/X0
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     31053    /run/user/1000/pulse/native
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     30021    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     31826    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     25366    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     25114    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     27686    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     16124    /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     52594    @/tmp/.X11-unix/X0
unix  2      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     44091    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     37985    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     29622    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     31092    /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     52601    /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     41395    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     34040    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     23505    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     35875    
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    35005    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     26472    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     27439    /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     29096    @/tmp/ibus/dbus-D0rlMWko
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     25539    /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     31134    @/tmp/dbus-7fOMHW7yZa
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     27403    /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    22648    
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    22270    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     27347    /run/user/1000/bus
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     32939    @/dbus-vfs-daemon/socket-BEuMgxxP
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     30890    /run/user/1000/bus
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     19272    /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     37219    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     30364    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     28175    @/tmp/.X11-unix/X0
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     31145    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     99574    /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     42200    /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     30372    /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     28533    @/tmp/.X11-unix/X0
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     24297    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     54399    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     29470    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     33812    /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    61280    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     32290    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     28553    /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     27249    /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     31146    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     22265    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     28543    @/tmp/dbus-7fOMHW7yZa
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     25394    /run/user/1000/bus
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     29275    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     30559    /run/user/1000/bus
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     30264    /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     29271    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     19271    /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     29601    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     30628    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     31892    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     25412    @/tmp/.X11-unix/X0
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     30130    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     2875     
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     24305    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     33058    /run/user/1000/bus
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     25440    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     29340    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     25219    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     52602    /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     37987    
unix  3      [ ]         SEQPACKET  CONECTADO     32297    
unix  3      [ ]         SEQPACKET  CONECTADO     30583    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     29594    
unix  3      [ ]         SEQPACKET  CONECTADO     30586    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     27336    /run/user/1000/bus
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     29876    /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     30629    @/tmp/.X11-unix/X0
unix  3      [ ]         SEQPACKET  CONECTADO     32296    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     29618    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     30304    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     28325    @/tmp/.X11-unix/X0
unix  3      [ ]         DGRAM                    14671    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     34030    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     24491    
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    28084    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     28603    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     27685    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     16126    /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     30627    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     32271    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     30327    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     66774    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     22273    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     48133    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     28565    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     26620    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     30321    /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     25214    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     26101    /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     25835    /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     37390    /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     32272    /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  3      [ ]         DGRAM                    15666    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     31144    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     101606   
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     30371    /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     28362    /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     25442    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     25367    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     27406    /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     23449    /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  3      [ ]         DGRAM                    14738    
unix  3      [ ]         FLUJO      CONECTADO     40177    /run/systemd/journal/stdout
```

...

Comment: As the answer from Gote Guru says, this is normal. For me it is usually enough to check the output of `netstat -tunap` which gives you a nice overview of open ports and connections.

Answer (score 0):

It's seems to be normal. Most of the connections you see are unix sockets. Unix sockets are internal connections (one kind of interprocess communication).

You can list tcp or udp connections exclusively with -t or -u switches.

ssh-agent can be installed without sshd. ssh-agent is used to make ssh (client!) connection easier by storing pwd in memory. sshd is a daemon process which listening on port 22. (I can't see such connection in the above list).